# Not able to add a foreign key in already existing tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, foreign-keys

```sql
CREATE TABLE Artist
(
    Id INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
    FirstName varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    LastName varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    Forname varchar(50) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE Song
(
    SongId INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
    Title varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    Length decimal(20, 6) NOT NULL,
    AlbumId int NOT NULL
);
```

My relations are many-to-many, so I have created an intermediary table. I'm trying to create some foreign key constraints for my table.

```sql
CREATE TABLE Artist_Song
(
    Id INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
    ArtistId int NOT NULL,
    SongId int NOT NULL
);

ALTER TABLE Artist_Song
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_artistsong_artist
FOREIGN KEY (ArtistId)
REFERENCES Artist(Id);

ALTER TABLE Artist_Song
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_artistsong_song
FOREIGN KEY (SongId)
REFERENCES Song(Id);
```

But I keep receiving this error message:

> Foreign key <fk_artistsong_song> references invalid column 'Id' in referenced table 'Song'

or

> Foreign key <fk_artistsong_artist> references invalid column 'Id' in referenced table 'Artist'

I also tried creating a new column along with the restriction:

```sql
ALTER TABLE Song_Genre
    ADD SongIdTest INT
    CONSTRAINT FK_Test
        FOREIGN KEY (SongId) 
        REFERENCES Song(Id)
```

But I'm facing the same stuff.

What am I'm missing here?

Comment: Please ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question. Please either ask re 1 bad query/function with obligatory [mre], including why you think it should return something else or are unsure at the 1st subexpression that it doesn't give what you expect or are stuck, justified by reference to authoritative documentation, or ask about your overall goal giving working parts you can do with justification & ideally a [mre]. Then misunderstood code doesn't belong. But please ask about unexpected behaviour 1st because misconceptions get in the way of your goal. [ask] [Help] Basic questions are faqs.

Comment: When isolated this will be a faq. Please before considering posting: Pin down code issues via [mre]. Read manuals/references & google error messages & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. SO/SE search is poor & literal & unusual, read the help. Google re googling/searching, including Q&A at [meta] & [meta.se]. [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) Reflect research in posts.

Comment: Side note: The extra `Id` primary key column in the join table is unnecessary should not be there. Instead create a multi-column primary key over the other two columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL Sever, your foreign key reference should be in the format of table_name(column_name). For song table, the id column provided in the description is named as songId instead of id. if that naming is indeed intended, the foreign key reference should be written as:

```
ALTER TABLE Artist_Song
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_artistsong_song
FOREIGN KEY (SongId)
REFERENCES Song(SongId);
```

Full DDL schema build after the above change are tested [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/23570):

```
CREATE TABLE Artist
(
    Id INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
    FirstName varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    LastName varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    Forname varchar(50) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE Song
(
    SongId INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
    Title varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    Length decimal(20, 6) NOT NULL,
    AlbumId int NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE Artist_Song
(
    Id INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
    ArtistId int NOT NULL,
    SongId int NOT NULL
);

ALTER TABLE Artist_Song
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_artistsong_artist
FOREIGN KEY (ArtistId)
REFERENCES Artist(Id);

ALTER TABLE Artist_Song
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_artistsong_song
FOREIGN KEY (SongId)
REFERENCES Song(SongId);
```

Answer (score 0):

The first Problem that yourcode has, is that you haven't added `NOT NULL` to the primary as you have to the bridge table, the must be defined identical

your primarry key in song isn't id it is songId

```
CREATE TABLE Artist
(
    Id INT NOT NULL  PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
    FirstName varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    LastName varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    Forname varchar(50) NOT NULL
);
```

```
CREATE TABLE Song
(
    SongId INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
    Title varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    Length decimal(20, 6) NOT NULL,
    AlbumId int NOT NULL
);
```

```
CREATE TABLE Artist_Song -- <- intermediary table
(
    Id INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
    ArtistId int NOT NULL,
    SongId int NOT NULL
);
```

```
ALTER TABLE Artist_Song
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_artistsong_artist
FOREIGN KEY (ArtistId)
REFERENCES Artist(Id);
```

```
ALTER TABLE Artist_Song
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_artistsong_song
FOREIGN KEY (SongId)
REFERENCES Song(SongId);
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/AgKGsruT)

Comment: PK implies not null, there is no not null "problem".

Comment: the code works now, and doesn't produce any error described by the user

Comment: That is irrelevant to my comment & this post is still wrong in the way my comment says.